# I am using ionic and getting an error: SyntaxError: Unexpected token < in JSON at position 0 at JSON.parse (<anonymous>)

Tags: javascript, php, angularjs, ionic-framework

This is my Code:

```
this.http.get('http://localhost/....)

      .map((res) => res.json())

      .subscribe((

        this.navCtrl.push(OtpPage,{mobileno:this.mobile});

      }, (err) => {
        console.log(err);
      });
```

and getting the following error:

SyntaxError: Unexpected token < in JSON at position 0
    at JSON.parse ()

Anyone can help Please??

Comment: The resource you're getting from your service on localhost isn't valid JSON. It seems to start with `<`.

Comment: Any idea how to solve this @Protectator, thanks.

Comment: Yes, verify that the service you're trying to get on `localhost` returns a correct JSON.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

as @Protectator mentioned, your response from the server is not valid JSON, and when the code tries to call **res.json()** it throws error.

Try it by removing/updating following snippet.

> .map((res) )